# Перевод из консоли в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, консоль

Помогите перевести код в WPF. DataGrid.

```
namespace HDA_Client
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string serverName = "Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1";
        var hdac = OPCHDA.Client();
        hdac.Connect(serverName);

        hdac.AddItem("Random.Int1");

        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime start = d.AddDays(-1);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

        DataTable dt = hdac.ReadRaw(start, end, 24, true);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
                dr["TimeStamp"].ToString(),
                dr["Value"].ToString(),
                dr["Quality"].ToString()));
        }

        hdac.Disconnect();
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эээ, а вы уже выучили WPF? Если нет, то вам нужно сначала выучить, это немаленький фреймворк. Если выучили, в каком конкретно месте возникает проблема?

Comment: Учу. Проблема в переносе данных в DataGrid. Не могу понять как правильно предоставить их таблице.